# Clojure.core source: Why ~@ (unquote-splicing operator) with a quoted double list inside, instead of ~ (unquote operator)

Tags: syntax, clojure, conventions, clojure-core

## Preamble

I was looking throught the source code in `clojure.core` for no particular reason.

I started reading `defmacro ns`, here is the abridged source:

```clj
(defmacro ns
  "...docstring..."
  {:arglists '([name docstring? attr-map? references*])
   :added "1.0"}
  [name & references]
  (let [... 
        ; Argument processing here.
        name-metadata (meta name)]
    `(do
       (clojure.core/in-ns '~name)
       ~@(when name-metadata
           `((.resetMeta (clojure.lang.Namespace/find '~name) ~name-metadata)))
       (with-loading-context
        ~@(when gen-class-call (list gen-class-call))
        ~@(when (and (not= name 'clojure.core) (not-any? #(= :refer-clojure (first %)) references))
            `((clojure.core/refer '~'clojure.core)))
        ~@(map process-reference references))
        (if (.equals '~name 'clojure.core) 
          nil
          (do (dosync (commute @#'*loaded-libs* conj '~name)) nil)))))
```

## Looking Closer

And then trying to read it I saw some strange macro patterns, in particular we can look at:

```clj
~@(when name-metadata
        `((.resetMeta (clojure.lang.Namespace/find '~name) ~name-metadata)))
```

### The `clojure.core` version

Here is a standalone working extraction from the macro:

```clj
(let [name-metadata 'name-metadata 
      name 'name]
  `(do
     ~@(when name-metadata
         `((.resetMeta (clojure.lang.Namespace/find '~name) ~name-metadata)))))

=> (do (.resetMeta (clojure.lang.Namespace/find (quote name)) name-metadata))
```

When I ran this could I couldn't help but wonder why there is a double list at the point `` `((.resetMeta ``.

### My version

I found that by just removing the unquote-splicing (`~@`) the double list was unnecessary. Here is a working standalone example:

```clj
(let [name-metadata 'name-metadata 
      name 'name]
  `(do
     ~(when name-metadata
         `(.resetMeta (clojure.lang.Namespace/find '~name) ~name-metadata))))

=> (do (.resetMeta (clojure.lang.Namespace/find (quote name)) name-metadata))
```

## My Question

Thus, why does clojure.core choose this seemingly extraneous way of doing things?

#### My Own Thoughts

Is this an artifact of convention?
Are there other similar instances where this is used in more complex ways?

Comment: You may wish to ask this question on the Clojure mailing list:  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/clojure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`~` always emits a form; `~@` can potentially emit nothing at all. Thus sometimes one uses `~@` to splice in a single expression conditionally:

```
;; always yields the form (foo x)
;; (with x replaced with its macro-expansion-time value):
`(foo ~x)`

;; results in (foo) is x is nil, (foo x) otherwise:
`(foo ~@(if x [x]))
```

That's what's going on here: the `(.resetMeta …)` call is emitted within the `do` form that `ns` expands to only if `name-metadata` is truthy (non-`false`, non-`nil`).

In this instance, it doesn't really matter – one could use `~`, drop the extra brackets and accept that the macroexpansion of an `ns` form with no name metadata would have an extra `nil` in the `do` form. For the sake of a prettier expansion, though, it makes sense to use `~@` and only emit a form to handle name metadata when it is actually useful.